# Is it possible to mix feminine suffix (in) and offspring suffix (id)?

Tags: affixes

**Well, let's start with an example.**

> A dog - Hundo.
>
> A puppy (The offset of a dog) - **Hundido**.
>
> A dog female - **Hundino**.

Now, can "puppy female" be written like **Hundidino** or **Hundinido**? (mixing both suffixes)

If so, is it possible to mix more suffixes and prefixes (Not meaning 'j', 'n', and suffixes that have something to do with grammar, but suffixes that add meaning to the word itself, like 'ge', 'id', 'in', etc) - 3, 4, and more? 
If so, does it make a lot of Esperanto words look like long and messy German words?

Comment: Being pedantic, I'd have to add that the affixes are _-in-_ and _-id-_ only; the _-o_ is the grammatical marker for a noun...

Comment: @OliverMason Just thought about it before reading this comment. Going to fix :-)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Yes you can. This can be done with all suffixes, with how many suffixes you want. But keep things reasonable. Only add a suffix when it adds a valuable information.

By the way, remember to read them from left to right, so even if you can "mix" the place of -id- and -in-, the results do not mean the same.

- **Hund-id**-in-o means a female **puppy**
- **Hund-in**-id-o means a puppy from a **female dog**

Comment: Another example I've had trouble with is whether "little sister" should be "fatineto" or "fratetino" .

Comment: Normally, one would use "fratineto" rather than "fratetino".